# what should i do to get the mathematics table in column format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a student and by running this code i am getting the output of 1 to 5 tables in a row however i want to have the output in such a manner that if the table of 2 is there then the table of 3 should be in next column like side by side. what should i include to achieve that result.To summarize i want the output to come in column format each table side by side and not that each table is below the other .

```
f=open('C:/python/1 to 5 table','w')
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range (1,11):
        print (i,'X',j,'=',i*j)
        f.write (string(i)+string('X')+string(j)+string('=')+string(i*j)+string('\n'))
f.close()
```

Comment: what is `string(..)`? NameError

Comment: try reversing the loop order - i first, then j. also: `f.write( f"{i} X {j} = {i*j}")` and you need to put some spaces after each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `string` should be `str`

also, you don't have to typecast a string to a `str`

```
f=open('table.txt','w')

for j in range (1,11):
    for i in range(1,6):
        # print (i,'X',j,'=',i*j)
        f.write (str(i)+str('X')+str(j)+str('=')+str(i*j)+str('\t')) # I don't like number of `str`'s, they are not needed for a string
    f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

Adviseable code

```
f=open('table.txt','w')

for j in range (1,11):
    for i in range(1,6):
        f.write (f'{i}X{j}={i*j}\t')
    f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

Output:

```
1X1=1   2X1=2   3X1=3   4X1=4   5X1=5   
1X2=2   2X2=4   3X2=6   4X2=8   5X2=10  
1X3=3   2X3=6   3X3=9   4X3=12  5X3=15  
1X4=4   2X4=8   3X4=12  4X4=16  5X4=20  
1X5=5   2X5=10  3X5=15  4X5=20  5X5=25  
1X6=6   2X6=12  3X6=18  4X6=24  5X6=30  
1X7=7   2X7=14  3X7=21  4X7=28  5X7=35  
1X8=8   2X8=16  3X8=24  4X8=32  5X8=40  
1X9=9   2X9=18  3X9=27  4X9=36  5X9=45  
1X10=10 2X10=20 3X10=30 4X10=40 5X10=50
```

Explanation:
I have reversed the loop order now loop[1-5] goes for 10 times/lines

PS:
`f` is used to format string!